# How to use completion handlers in firebase in SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, swiftui, firebase-storage

I am a beginner in swiftUI and I would like to know how to use the completion handler (I think this what I need) to  upload an image from firebase storage passing two parameters to a function and receiving a UIIimage, could you help me? async/await are not valid for me.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage

struct Inicio2View: View {

    @State private var image: Image = Image(systemName: "person.fill")
    
    
    var body: some View {

                       image
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                            .border (Color.gray,width: 3.0)
                            .onAppear(perform: {
                                self.image = Image(uiImage: loadImage(userID: "user1212",imageName: "image1212"))
                                }
     }
}

func loadImage(userID: String, imagename: String) -> UIImage {
    
    
    @State var uii = UIImage()
   
    
    let url = "IOsimages/\(userID)/\(imagename).jpg"
            let storage = Storage.storage()
            let ref = storage.reference().child(url)
            ref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                }else{
                    uii = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    var _ = print("image found")
                    
                }
              
    
    return uii //first return without completing the asynchronous task of firebase
}
```

I will appreciate any response. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure your code. This should do the trick:

```
struct Inicio2View: View {
    //Don´t save the image here
//@State private var image: Image = Image(systemName: "person.fill")
@State private var image: UIImage?

var body: some View {
        //decide which image to show
        if image != nil{
            Image(uiImage: image!)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                .border (Color.gray,width: 3.0)
                
        }else{
            Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                .border (Color.gray,width: 3.0)
                .onAppear{
                    loadImage(userID: "user1212", imagename: "image1212")
                }
        }
}

//change signature of function
func loadImage(userID: String, imagename: String) {
    
    //remove this
    //@State var uii = UIImage()
    
    let url = "IOsimages/\(userID)/\(imagename).jpg"
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let ref = storage.reference().child(url)
    ref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }else{
            //assign image here
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                image = UIImage(data: data!)!
            }
            print("image found")
            
        }
    }
}
}
```